# How to group a hash?

Tags: ruby

I got a hash (see below) that I need to group but I have no idea how to do it.
I will use this array for table sections in iOS (Rubymotion).

The hash looks like this and I want to group by profession:

```
[{"firstname" => "John", "lastname" => "Wayne", "profession" => "actor"},{"firstname" => "Oliva", "lastname" => "Newton", "profession" => "actor"},{"firstname" => "Terry", "lastname" => "Gilliam", "profession" => "director"}]
```

I need it to look like this:

```
["actor" => [{"firstname" => "John", "lastname" => "Wayne", "profession" => "actor"},{"firstname" => "Oliva", "lastname" => "Newton", "profession" => "actor"}], "director" =>[{"firstname" => "Terry", "lastname" => "Gilliam", "profession" => "director"}]
```

**Update**

It would be really good if I could get this structure:

```
{
    "profession" => "actor",
    "people" =>
    [
      {"firstname"=>"John", "lastname"=>"Wayne", "profession"=>"actor"},
      {"firstname" => "Oliva", "lastname" => "Newton", "profession" => "actor"}
    ],
"profession" => "director",
    "people" =>
    [
      {"firstname" => "Terry", "lastname" => "Gilliam", "profession" => "director"}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: You input has wrong structure

Comment: Your updated structure is even worse.

Comment: You can't have that structure, the `"people"` key can't be present more than once in the same hash

Comment: @mdesantis That is not the problem. There is no problem writing a hash literal with the same key twice; the former key would be simply overridden by a later one, which only means that the expression is redundant. There is a larger flaw.

Comment: @sawa indeed: `{ "people" => "mdesantis", "people" => "sawa"} #=> {"people"=>"sawa"}` But in this way you loose the former data

Comment: @mdesantis Yes. There is nothing wrong with that, except that it is a very redundant way of writing such a hash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do as below using [`Enumerable#group_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) :

```
a = [ 
        {"firstname" => "John", "lastname" => "Wayne", "profession" => "actor"},
        {"firstname" => "Oliva", "lastname" => "Newton", "profession" => "actor"},
        {"firstname" => "Terry", "lastname" => "Gilliam", "profession" => "director"}
    ]

a.group_by { |h| h["profession"] }
```

**output :**

```
{  "actor"=> [
             {"firstname"=>"John", "lastname"=>"Wayne", "profession"=>"actor"}, 
             {"firstname"=>"Oliva", "lastname"=>"Newton", "profession"=>"actor"}
            ], 
    "director"=> [
             {"firstname"=>"Terry", "lastname"=>"Gilliam", "profession"=>"director"}
                 ]
}
```

**update** ( As [@mdesantis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21904737/how-to-group-a-hash#comment33175749_21904737)  mentioned, your expected output is not the correct one, so I did change the structure to something meaningful.

```
a = [ 
        {"firstname" => "John", "lastname" => "Wayne", "profession" => "actor"},
        {"firstname" => "Oliva", "lastname" => "Newton", "profession" => "actor"},
        {"firstname" => "Terry", "lastname" => "Gilliam", "profession" => "director"}
    ]

result_hash = a.group_by { |h| h["profession"] }.map do |key,val|
    {"profession" => key, "people" => val}
end

p result_hash
```

**output**

```
[
    {"profession"=>"actor", 
    "people"=> [ {"firstname"=>"John", "lastname"=>"Wayne", "profession"=>"actor"},
                 {"firstname"=>"Oliva", "lastname"=>"Newton", "profession" =>"actor"}
                ]
    },
    {"profession"=>"director",
    "people"=>[ {"firstname"=>"Terry", "lastname"=>"Gilliam", "profession"=>"director"}
              ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks! I have updated my question a bit. Please have a look.

Comment: @JonathanClark Please check.

Comment: I am not ignoring anyone! I needed time to check it @sawa! Works fine now.